# Wireless Redstone Lamp without Command Blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

So I want to create a building that shows no Redstone. And one of the problem is the lighting. I really want to see if I could get a Redstone lamp float above ground by 1 block and be able to be turned on/off. I could not get the: "pushing armorstand+minecart into block to activate pressure plate under the redstone lamp" ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSO4UthRLMQ)) thing working as the armor stand only activated the pressure plate for 2 seconds. Then it stopped for some reason (probably fell down a few pixels or something).

Comment: I think is impossible. I saw something likeyou're asking but the redstone lamp had some redstone arround it.

Comment: What about a fix for the armorstand+minecart trick?

Comment: I don't udesrtand you question... For doing that I think you need command blocks.

Comment: @spund3 This is what I was talking about: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSO4UthRLMQ)

The armor stand only activated the pressure plate for 2 seconds or so.

Comment: Please add more detail such as... where the redstone lamp is in the building (i could answer your question if I knew this)

Comment: BUD piston maybe? (if it's still needed :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, using:

```
/setblock x y z lit_redstone_lamp
```

Is the only way to do this, and the lamp will turn off if any adjacent block update occur, such as blocks placed or items being used on it. It is a bit buggy, but it is the best I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: The solutions I have for you take up a lot of space, for redstone lamps, I suggest you think through the build before using it. Also I had to use command blocks (There is no way to do it without the command blocks)**

I think that the second method will work best for you but you might want to read them all.

I did make wireless redstone once (not just for a lamp) wireless redstone has become far more easy with the implementation of the summon or fill command.

You will have to make an action trigger, a redstone signal and also trigger an action to revert the first action. (I promise this will make sense)

I don't have minecraft avaiable right now so I can't show screenshots right now but anyway, this is what you want to do.

## The summon villager method

Here we will activate a piece redstone dust using a summond villager. this design has the largest reciever but it is lag friendly and easy to understand. Also the reciever can be hidden in any ceiling but not in the floor.

**1.** Write down the exact coordinates of the redstone dust you use to trigger the lamp. round them off to whole numbers.

**2.** Add 3 to the `Y` coordinate.

**3.** Directly above the redstone dust, of which you just wrote down the coordinates,  place a solid block of your choise and place a pressure plate on this block (either wood or stone, not the weighted ones)

**4.** Make a 1x2x1 (`X`,`Y`,`Z`) room around the pressure plate so a villager can fit in but can't walk off the pressure plate.

**5.** Think of a way to kill the villager after he has done his job of activating the pressure plate like using the `\kill` command, which I suggest you do. put this command on a slight delay. the length that you want your redstone signal to be activated depends on the time between the villager hitting the presure plate and him dying.

**Golden Redstone Rule:** *for every tick of delay your readstone signal is on for 0,1 second making 10 ticks a second of delay*

You can achieve this delay by using repeaters bewteen the redstone under your presure plate and the command block that will kill him.

**6.** Setup your summon command to summon a villager at the coordinates that you wrote down before.

**Summing up what will happen**

The villager when summond lands on the presure plate, activating the redstone signal below it. this will ,after a short delay set by the repeaters inbetween the redstone signal and the killing mechanism, kill the villager and the redstone signal turns back off.

**Problems**

There are three problems with this design:

**1.** The sender and receiver have to be loaded by minecraft to make it work.

**2.** You will loose track of the redstone signal timing of the sender (the time that the sender signal is on)

**3.** Summoning the mob might take some time to get him in the right spot if you got the coordinates off (after making a few of these devices you will get the hang of it though)

**Solution for problem N.2**

The solution to this problem is killing the villager with the same signal as it is summond with. to do this you will have to put a repeater going into the commandblock that summons the villager. leave it at one tick of delay. now before the repeater place a redstone torch in a way that it deactivates by activating your input signal. Now place the commandblock that kills the villager so the torch will activate it. now remove the killing system at the reciever module.

## The redstone block setblock method

Here we will power the lamp directly with a setblock command by "setblocking" a redstone block underneath it. this has the smalest reciver of the two (only the redstone block if you destroy it from the sender) also it can be placed anywhere (floor, wall or ceiling) it is a bit harder to understand it though.

**1.** Write down your coordinates of the block to power and choose the side to power it from (use F3 here to see what side it is)

**2.**  Subtract or add to 1 to the coordinates depending on the side you want to power the block from (-1 on the `Y` acces to power it from below) this may require some testing.

**3.** determine where the sender has to be. Setup you command block to setblock the redstone block in the coordinates you just got. then write in this command block the next command:

```
setblock X Y Z minecraft:redstone_block 0
```

**4.** Setup another command block to destroy the redstone (either at the reciver for a fixed time or at the sender for a variable time depending on the timing of the sender's input) use this command:

```
setblock X Y Z minecraft:air 0
```

The wiring is the same as with the villager summon method

you can also setup two buttons. one for turning on the redstone block, one for turning it of. Just connect one commandblock to one button ant the other command block to another button. this will result in a RS latch style sender.

**Problems**

**1.** You might want to turn off the tile drops using:`gamerule doTileDrops false`. this will turn off all block drops though

**2.** You might have trouble understanding the way this works (even I sometimes do when it does not work)

**3.** Calculating the coordinate if you want to power it from the side is hard if you do it for the first time. This is where you will have to experiment.

I hope you can use these designs. I will post some screenshots when I get home tonight

Comment: "Wireless Redstone Lamp ***without Command Blocks***?" Also, I see no reason to use `destroy` in the second case, that just makes everything laggy AF. Lastly, asking someone to turn off tile drops without explaining that that will break survival mode completely is no good at all.

Comment: @MrLemon can't be done, this is the only solution at this time

Comment: @MrLemon your right about the `destroy` thing though, editing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you can do with this, but try using a sticky piston attached to a redstone block. I'm not the most experienced with redstone, but I was trying to figure out my own problem when I came across this question.

Comment: Could you provide some more details on how this might work? Even if you don't have much experience with redstone, you can still share some things you have tried that might get the OP one step closer to an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in MC Bedrock you can use the setblock method. I will explain.

### The setblock method

1. Place a **repeat** command block.

   Enter in the following command:

   ***setblock ~ ~ ~ lit_redstone_lamp***   **

   Apply redstone to the command block.

I use this loads in my worlds.

***Make sure to replace ~ ~ ~ with the coordinates of the block and don’t put ** at the end of the command or it won’t work.*